# Is there any way to run a Windows 10 Mobile app in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 tablet. [Instagram is available for Windows 10 Mobile](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/instagram-beta/9nblggh5l9xt) - but not Windows 10.

**Is there any way to run a Windows 10 Mobile app in Windows 10?**

Comment: Only if it's a UWP.  The app in question is not

Comment: @Ramhound How do you know if the app is UWP or not? The Instagram mobile app is brand new. It might not be on non-phone devices just because it's UI is designed for phones - eg, iOS version is not available for iPads either.

Comment: on the store it shows that the App in only compiled for mobile CPUs (ARM), so the app doesn't work on x86 Windows 10 devices